# How to get the row count of the column in r

Tags: r, datatable, apply

i am trying to get the count of the column without changing the values but i can't because of the date column has been changed as numeric (For more clarification kindly check the below image). So let me know how to crack this issue

Sample data

```
 structure(list(Incubatee = c("Janitri", "Janitri"), partnership_type = c("GTM", 
    "GTM"), plan_end_date = c("2021-06-30", "2021-06-30")), row.names = c(NA, 
    -2L), groups = structure(list(Incubatee = "Janitri", .rows = structure(list(
        1:2), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", 
    "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
    "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The function which i wrote to get the count

```
create_Incubatee_section = function(Incubatee_data) {
  main_row = data.frame(
    Incubatee = Incubatee_data$Incubatee[1],
    partnership_type = "",
    plan_end_date = nrow(Incubatee_data)
    
  ) 
  
  partnership_type_rows = lapply(
    Incubatee_data$partnership_type,
    function(inc) {
      data.frame(
        Incubatee = "",
        partnership_type = inc,
        plan_end_date = sum(Incubatee_data$partnership_type == inc)
      )
    }
  )
  Reduce(rbind, x = c(list(main_row), partnership_type_rows))
}

expand_collapse = function(data) {
  Incubatee_data = split(data, data$Incubatee)
  Incubatee_sections = lapply(Incubatee_data, create_Incubatee_section)
  total_row = data.frame(
    Incubatee = "Total",
    partnership_type = "",
    plan_end_date = nrow(data)
    
  )
  Reduce(rbind, x = c(Incubatee_sections, list(total_row)))
}


DT::datatable(expand_collapse(x), rownames = F,escape = FALSE,selection=list(mode="single",target="row"),options = list(pageLength = 50,scrollX = TRUE,dom = 'tp',ordering=F,columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE),list(className = 'dt-left', targets = '_all'))),class='hover cell-border stripe')
```

Expected output

[image: Expected Output]

Current output

[image: Current Output]

Comment: Not clear enough. Input is your sample data,  what's your specific output? (you can also show it in code format as the sample data) What do you mean when you say the count of the column? (count what, which columns)

Comment: the count of plan_end_date column and now i seperate the image as current and expected output kindly check @PeaceWang

Answer (score 0):

I tried, but there were some difficulties.

```r
x<-structure(list(Incubatee = c("Janitri", "Janitri"), partnership_type = c("GTM", "GTM"),
                  plan_end_date = c("2021-06-30", "2021-06-30")), row.names = c(NA, -2L),
             groups = structure(list(Incubatee = "Janitri", 
                                     .rows = structure(list(1:2), ptype = integer(0), 
                                                       class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", "date"))), 
                                row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df","tbl", "data.frame"))

create_Incubatee_section = function(Incubatee_data) {
  main_row = data.frame(
    Incubatee = Incubatee_data$Incubatee[1],
    partnership_type = "",
    plan_end_date = ""
    
  ) 
  
  partnership_type_rows = lapply(
    Incubatee_data[,2:3],
    function(inc) {
      data.frame(
        Incubatee = "",
        partnership_type = inc[1],
        plan_end_date = inc[2]
      )
    }
  )
  
  Reduce(rbind, x = c(list(main_row), partnership_type_rows))
}


expand_collapse = function(data) {
  Incubatee_data = split(data, data$Incubatee)
  Incubatee_sections = lapply(Incubatee_data, create_Incubatee_section)
  total_row = data.frame(
    Incubatee = "Total",
    partnership_type = "",
    plan_end_date = nrow(data)
    
  )
  Reduce(rbind, x = c(Incubatee_sections, list(total_row)))
}


DT::datatable(expand_collapse(x), rownames = F,escape = FALSE,selection=list(mode="single",target="row"),
              options = list(pageLength = 50,scrollX = TRUE,dom = 'tp',ordering=F,
                             columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE),list(className = 'dt-left', targets = '_all'))),class='hover cell-border stripe')
```

[image]

You should modify the partnership_type_rows = ~ for complete result.

Comment: using  partnership_type_rows = ~ i am getting an Error in rep(xi, length.out = nvar) : 
  attempt to replicate an object of type 'language' and also kindly check the expected output